# How do you update a nested array with Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

This is what I have so far. This is my AnswerSchema with a comments array nested within that I am trying to update.

```
const AnswerSchema = new Schema({
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user',
      },
      question: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'question',
      },
      text: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      name: {
        type: String,
      },
      avatar: {
        type: String,
      },
      views: {
        type: Number,
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      },
      answerLikes: [
        {
          user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'user',
          },
        },
      ],
      comments: [
        {
          user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'user',
          },
          text: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
          name: {
            type: String,
          },
          avatar: {
            type: String,
          },
          commentLikes: [
            {
              user: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'user',
              },
            },
          ],
          date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
          },
        },
      ],
    })
```

and here is my update route that I am trying to use to update the comments array text field

```
try {
    const updatedAnswer = await Answer.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.answer_id },
      {
        $set: { 'comments.$[comment].text': formattedAnswer },
      },
      {
        arrayFilters: [{'comment._id': req.params.comment_id }],
      },
      { new: true }
    )
    res.json(updatedAnswer)
```

I keep getting the error 'Callback must be a function, got [object Object]' and cant figure out a fix.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are passing 4 parameters to the `findOneAndUpdate` function.
The 4th argument is a callback which accepts a function:

```js
(err /* an error if occurred */, doc /* the updated document */) => {}
```

In order to solve that you need to combine your last 2 arguments into one object like:

```js
{
    arrayFilters: [{'comment._id': req.params.comment_id }],
    new: true
}
```

Final query:

```js
const updatedAnswer = await Answer.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.answer_id },
    {
        $set: { 'comments.$[comment].text': formattedAnswer },
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [{'comment._id': req.params.comment_id }],
        new: true
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 4th argument in findOneAndUpdate function takes in a callback function that was where your error was.

Try this

```
try{

  const updatedAnswer = await Answer.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: req.params.answer_id },
   {
      $set: { 'comments.$[comment].text': formattedAnswer },
   },
   {
     arrayFilters: [{'comment._id': req.params.comment_id }],
     new: true
   }
   );

   res.json(updatedAnswer);

}catch(err){
  //console.log(err)
}
```